# Using Parameters in an sql statement which contains date_format

Tags: mysql, date, parameters

In a query such as:

```
Select * from table_name Where DATE_FORMAT(dateTime, '%d.%m.%Y') = '%s'
```

In this query i want to use parameters for '%s', but in this case %d - which is in the date format -  also behaves like a parameter and the query takes the parameter for %d instead of %s.

it is not so important, I just wondered if there is a solution. Othervise the query can be written in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIMESTAMP can also be used as the first argument to GET_FORMAT(), in which case the function returns the same values as for DATETIME.

mysql> `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2003-10-03',GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR'));`
        -> '03.10.2003'

mysql> `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10.31.2003',GET_FORMAT(DATE,'USA'));`
        -> '2003-10-31'

> GET_FORMAT()

is available as of MySQL 4.1.1.

See [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) Link.